# How to update multiple records in an array in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like:

```
classID: String,

students: [

    {
       id: String,
       name: String,
       marks: Number,
       status: String
    }
]
```

Now, I have a requirement to update all the student records with status "pass" to have the marks as 35.

Please let me know what is the best way to do it.

I tried with:

```
$set: {"students.$.marks" : 0}
```

but it just updated the first matched record.

Then I observed that I can do it by index:

```
$set: {"students.0.marks" : 0}, 
$set: {"students.1.marks" : 0}
```

and I was able to update the first two records, how can I update all the records in the array or the record which satisfy the condition?

Comment: Honestly, your schema seems pretty inefficient.  You just have everything shoved in one big array.

Answer (score 0):

First get all records as per your criteria then do loop on records and in the loop you can update records.

```
students.find({makers > 35 }, function(err,data))
```

{
    for loop {
     update records
    }
}